Error while adding Scaffold Item for Identity in .NETCore - 'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for Project'
Task is to create an identity scaffold item in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC. For that, I modified the ApplicationDbContext base class from DbContext to IdentityDbContext in data access project and installed the nuget package Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore version 8.0.0 in the same project.
Next I'm trying to add scaffold identity item in the web application - but it throws the following error:

There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'ProjectName'.'

Here is the ApplicationDbContext class screenshot from the data access project:

This is the error message thrown in web project:


The sample is not reproducible, please provide a minimal reproducible example. The error is usually caused by version or reference conflicts of nudget packages, please provide your ProjectName.csproj.

Yes, cause of the issue is version 8.0.0, when I changed it to 8.0.7 now able to add the identity scaffold item in web project. Thank you
